# How to reduce Analysis Phase's elapsed time in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have a Bazel project with 693 targets which consumes 5 minutes in the *Analysis Phase* which is 94 percent of the complete build time. Is there a way to reduce the *Analysis Phase*'s time cost?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [Performance profiling](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/performance.html#performance-profiling) to find out what is the critical part. Maybe there is some room for optimization.